# Почему не устанавливается текст в Label?

Tags: java, javafx

Я пытаюсь сделать приложение по типу счётчика калорий: в первом окне я вписываю текущий рост и вес, а во втором окне в текстовом поле Label я должен вывести "Ваш текущий рост и вес: " + Height + " см и " + Weight + " кг.". К сожалению, текст не устанавливается, в чём причина?

**FXML файл первого окна:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>


<AnchorPane prefHeight="480.0" prefWidth="720.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.heightAndWeightController">
   <children>
      <Label layoutX="255.0" layoutY="26.0" prefHeight="62.0" prefWidth="211.0" text="Введите Ваш рост и вес">
         <font>
            <Font size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <TextField fx:id="fieldHeight" layoutX="274.0" layoutY="124.0" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="161.0" promptText="Рост" />
      <TextField fx:id="fieldWeight" layoutX="274.0" layoutY="195.0" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="161.0" promptText="Вес" />
      <Button fx:id="nextButton" layoutX="313.0" layoutY="310.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="83.0" text="Далее" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**Контроллер первого окна:**

```
package sample;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class heightAndWeightController {

    public int Weight;
    public int Height;

    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    private TextField fieldHeight;

    @FXML
    private TextField fieldWeight;

    @FXML
    private Button nextButton;

    @FXML
    void initialize() {
        nextButton.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
            Weight = Integer.parseInt(fieldWeight.getText());
            Height = Integer.parseInt(fieldHeight.getText());

            nextButton.getScene().getWindow().hide();
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(heightAndWeightController.class.getResource("/sample/sample.fxml"));
            try {
                loader.load();
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Parent root = loader.getRoot();
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            stage.show();
            stage.setResizable(false);
        });
    }

}
```

**Контроллер окна, в котором должен выводится текст:**

```
package sample;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class Controller extends heightAndWeightController{

@FXML
private ResourceBundle resources;

@FXML
private URL location;

@FXML
private Label currentHaWLable;

@FXML
void initialize() {
   currentHaWLable.setText("Ваш текущий рост и вес: " + Height + " см и " + Weight + " кг.");
  }
}
```

FXML файл окна, в котором должен выводится текст:

```
**<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>


<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="480.0" prefWidth="717.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Label layoutX="260.0" layoutY="38.0" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="109.0" text="Калории" textAlignment="CENTER">
         <font>
            <Font name="Segoe UI Italic" size="25.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <ProgressBar layoutX="260.0" layoutY="96.0" prefWidth="200.0" progress="0.0" />
      <DatePicker layoutX="274.0" layoutY="124.0" />
      <Label layoutX="133.0" layoutY="183.0" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="109.0" text="Завтрак" textAlignment="CENTER">
         <font>
            <Font name="Segoe UI Italic" size="25.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label layoutX="133.0" layoutY="281.0" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="109.0" text="Обед" textAlignment="CENTER">
         <font>
            <Font name="Segoe UI Italic" size="25.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label layoutX="133.0" layoutY="366.0" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="109.0" text="Ужин" textAlignment="CENTER">
         <font>
            <Font name="Segoe UI Italic" size="25.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <ScrollPane layoutX="260.0" layoutY="183.0" prefHeight="71.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
      <ScrollPane layoutX="260.0" layoutY="270.0" prefHeight="71.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
      <ScrollPane layoutX="260.0" layoutY="355.0" prefHeight="71.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
      <Label layoutX="390.0" layoutY="35.0" prefHeight="57.0" prefWidth="117.0" text="1200/1800">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Italic" size="19.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label fx:id="currentHaWLable" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="13.0" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="200.0" text="" textAlignment="CENTER">
         <font>
            <Font name="Segoe UI Italic" size="12.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>**
```

Comment: Скорее всего у вас не подцепился ваш класс-контроллер, т.к. не вижу его упоминаний в `fxml` и в коде (что-то по типу `loader.setController( new Controller() );`).

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло, но теперь не понятно, как сохранить переменные для обеих окон. Во втором окне они выводятся по нулям(

Comment: `import java.awt.*;` - вот этого в коде с javafx не должно быть. Из-за этого у вас контролы могут импортироваться из другого GUI фреймворка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего у вас не подцепился ваш класс-контроллер, т.к. не вижу его упоминаний

a) ни в `fxml`:

```
<AnchorPane fx:controller="sample.Controller"...>
```

b) ни в коде:

```
loader.setController( new Controller() );
```

> Спасибо, это помогло, но теперь не понятно, как сохранить переменные для обеих окон. Во втором окне они выводятся по нулям(

Т.к. вы генерируете новое окно, т.е. новый объект, при каждом клике, то можно сделать, например, так:

```
public class Controller extends heightAndWeightController{

    private final int weight;
    private final int height;

    public Controller( int weight, int height ) {
        this.weight = weight;
        this.height = height;
    }

    ....
}


nextButton.setOnAction( actionEvent -> {
    ...
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setController( new Controller( weight, height ) );
    ...
}
```